Nuxt content render the layout twice
I was trying to render an .md article with a vue layout. but the layout is rendered twice. one inside another.
I am using the following layout:
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>container</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .container{
        padding: 2em;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
    }
    .content{
        padding: 2em;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: blue;
    }
    
</style>

and the following markdown file:
---
layout: debug
---


# test  
testt

but I got the following result:

I have look into this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1722 but when a apply the solution it would not work and return 404.
here is my nuxt.config.ts for additional information:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@nuxt/image", "@nuxt/content"],
  content: {
    documentDriven: true
  },
  
})


found the problem.
I replace the  <slot />  tag with <ContentDoc />. I followed this  documentation
So it should be something like:
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>container</h1>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
            <ContentDoc />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .container{
        padding: 2em;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
    }
    .content{
        padding: 2em;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: blue;
    }
   
</style>

